# Button Class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to create a class for button control by inheriting the button property. I want to add more property in the default property by creating new button class

Initially New Property Will be like: 1) Bottom and Top Color
2) Round Corner

See code below

'Below is the code I've tried

```
 Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Property TopColor As Color
    Public Property BottomColor As Color

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim lgb As LinearGradientBrush = New 
          LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, Me.TopColor, 
          Me.BottomColor, 90.0F)
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        g.FillRectangle(lgb, Me.ClientRectangle)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When i'm assigning color to the Top and Bottom Color property color of bottom is not changing. Even I'm not getting any error message

Comment: Call `Invalidate()` in the properties setter (requires a backing field).

Comment: Hi Jimi, Could you please edit the code and post it? I'm beginner. I have created this code by copying from panel class. But It's doesn't work for Button.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make use of the Properties Setter (and Getter, of course), so you can call [Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) when a property value is changed. This raises the `Paint` event, causing the Control to re-paint itself.
The code in the `OnPaint` method will redraw the Button's graphics, using the new Colors.

You also need to paint the Button's Text, since it's deleted when we paint the Button's content.
This also implies that we consider the **`TextAlign`** property, to redraw the Text in the right position.
I'm using [StrinFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat) here to align the Text as defined by the Button's `TextAlign` property.
See the **`GetVerticalAlignment()`** and **`GetHorizontalAlignment()`** methods.

Last but not least, the Background and Foreground brushes must be disposed of, to avoid leaking graphics resource. So does the `StringFormat` object.
We just need to declare these objects with [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statements and use them inside the `Using` blocks.
This will take care of disposing of these object when we're done with them.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Private m_TopColor As Color = Color.LightGreen
    Private m_BottomColor As Color = Color.Orange

    Public Property TopColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_TopColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            m_TopColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BottomColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_BottomColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            m_BottomColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Using lgb As LinearGradientBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, m_TopColor, m_BottomColor, 90.0F)
            Using textBrush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
                Using format As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
                    format.Alignment = GetHorizontalAlignment()
                    format.LineAlignment = GetVerticalAlignment()
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, Me.ClientRectangle)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, textBrush, Me.ClientRectangle, format)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function GetVerticalAlignment() As StringAlignment
        Return CType(Math.Log(Me.TextAlign, 2D) / 4, StringAlignment)
    End Function

    Private Function GetHorizontalAlignment() As StringAlignment
        Return CType(Math.Log(Me.TextAlign, 2D) Mod 4, StringAlignment)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hi Jimi, You are fantastic. Thank You for your time. One small help, how can I make the button corner rounder?

Comment: One more problem button Image is not showing. Might be it is overlaping by the top and bottom color?

Comment: You should modify a Control's [Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.region) (see the sample code there), using [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) or, in this case, with [CreateRoundRectRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createroundrectrgn) or [CreatePolygonRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createpolygonrgn). The result may not be so great though, you need a lot more work to make it *feel right*.

Comment: If you have a Bitmap (which you didn't mention in the question), you'll have to draw it yourself. See the [Graphics.DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) method. Consider the Button's [TextImageRelation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.textimagerelation) property to position it correctly.

Comment: I'm known about the basic coding. If you can post the code that will be a great help. I'm expecting 2 additional propery in that button 1. It should have gradient color like you helped above and 2. It can have round corner. Rest of the property should work as they work normal. It seems that in the abobe code you are overlaping the base color with the new color and base text with the new text?

Comment: If you have a question about the implementation of a rounded region, in relation to a custom control, make a new question, showing the code you have tried. Your current code is related to the painting of a Control's canvas (plus the Text, which I added for completeness). -- If you modify a Control, to make it look different from the standard implementation, you need to recreate all the parts that you substitute. Since you're painting the Control, everything that's normally painted by the standard implementation needs to be recreated by your, new, implementation.